# Using a string instead of URL as an entityID with SAML

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, saml, moodle, saml-2.0

We are implementing a SSO with `SAML` and `Moodle 3.3`'s plugin https://moodle.org/plugins/auth_saml2

Usually moodle provides an `entityID` as an URL, for example:

```
entityID="https://mymoodlesite.com/auth/saml2/sp/metadata.php"
```

Our partner is requesting in this case a simple string, someting like:

```
external-moodle
```

According to the SAML specifications entityID could only be a `URL`, is there a workaround with the example above?

Answer (score 2):

SAML meta data schema defines entityID as

```
<simpleType name="entityIDType">
    <restriction base="anyURI">
        <maxLength value="1024"/>   
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

anyURI is defined at https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-xmlschema11-2-20060217/#anyURI

even using

```
external-moodle
```

as entityID would pass SAML meta data schema check. For interoperability it SHOULD be an URL - https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/51890/SAML%20MD%20simplified%20overview.pdf